# Future-proof defun - use if available, define equivalent if not

Tags: emacs, elisp, future-proof

I'm using emacs 24.3 right now, so `hash-table-values` is not available. So I want to write the function, but only if it doesn't exist. This way, my code works right now, and it'll use the default function when I'll switch to emacs 24.4.

In PHP, I'd write something like:

```
if (!function_exists('hash_table_values')) {
    function hash_table_values() {}
}
```

Is there some equivalent in elisp?

Comment: Note that even in 24.4, `hash-table-values` is only available if you explicitly require `subr-x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to some guidance on #emacs@freenode, here is the magic function: [`fboundp`](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_check_defined.html).

```
(unless (fboundp 'fn)
  (defun fn ()))
```

For the real implementation of `hash-table-values`:

```
(unless (fboundp 'hash-table-values)
  (defun hash-table-values (hashtable)
    (let (allvals)
      (maphash (lambda (_kk vv) (push vv allvals)) hashtable)
    allvals)))
```

Thanks to ergoemacs for the [hash-table-values](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_hash_table.html) implementation.

Comment: `(setq x (cons v x)` can be shortened to `(push v x)`.  Also, adding a leading underscore to the unused name `kk` avoids a warning about an unused lexical variable, in case lexical binding is enabled.